# Is it safe to delete APEX tables and some dummy data in oracle database xe 11.2

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

i created a database schema in 11g Express Edition, however there are some APEX tables and some dummy data...

```
APEX$_ACL                      TABLE
APEX$_WS_FILES                 TABLE
APEX$_WS_HISTORY               TABLE
APEX$_WS_LINKS                 TABLE
APEX$_WS_NOTES                 TABLE
APEX$_WS_ROWS                  TABLE
APEX$_WS_TAGS                  TABLE
APEX$_WS_WEBPG_SECTIONS        TABLE
APEX$_WS_WEBPG_SECTION_HISTORY TABLE
```

Is it safe to delete them? Also I would like to know what does APEX mean and why they have a dollar sign?

Comment: [Introducing Oracle Application Express](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11946/intro_app.htm#TDPAX01000) (the full name for APEX.)

Answer (score 0):

These tables are associated with Application Express Websheets.  It's safe to remove them.  I highly recommend you move them through the workspace administration of APEX.  I'm not sure what version of APEX you're using (APEX 18.1 is the latest), but [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEADM/understanding-workspace-administration.htm#AEADM324) are the instructions to remove them in APEX 5.1.

Oracle APEX is the low-code application development platform included with every Oracle Database.  Feel free to visit https://apex.oracle.com to learn more.