# Oracle Apex - Can I delete APEX$ tables from schema safely

Tags: oracle-apex

We just updated to APEX 23.1 from APEX 19.  We have some objects labelled APEX$ (triggers) which wont compile.

I was wondering (we don't use Web Sheet applications), if we can safely delete these tables in the schema, and the associated triggers and sequences.  the ACL table sounds important, but has no data in it (none of them have records).

[image]

We have a trigger "APEX$_WS_ROWS_T1" related to one of these tables which won't compile, as it is looking for a table called "apex_ws_data_grid_col" which doesn't exist.

I am not sure how many of these are critical tables APEX needs, or what can safely be deleted.

When I create a brand new workspace and schema in 23.1, none of these tables were created in the new schema, so think these are just "artefacts" from prior versions of APEX, or from when (at some point) we played around with Websheet applications.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746033/is-it-safe-to-delete-apex-tables-and-some-dummy-data-in-oracle-database-xe-11-2) answer it should be fine to delete them